# Azure devops multi-stage YAML combined with manual interaction

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline

I'm just reading about the [multi-stage pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema) which sound awesome.

As far I understand, the stages run after each other, now suppose I have the following stages

```
stages:
   stage: Deploy to acc
      ...
   stage: Deploy to prd
```

I don't want to run the production deployment right after the deployment to `acc`. First I want to look at `acc` and when I approve it should deploy to `prd`. Is there a way in the multi-stage pipeline to tell not to automatically run a stage? And run a stage manually for example? Or should I create a new pipeline just for production?

Comment: Was below answer helpful to you? did you have a try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent stage from automatically run, you can add conditions to each stage. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions) for more information

```
stages:
- stage: A
  #stage B runs if A fails
- stage: B
  condition: failed()
 #stage C runs if B succeeds
- stage: C
  dependsOn:
  - A
  - B
  condition: succeeded('B')
```

If you want to run a stage mannually. You can create `checks` for your `environments`.
Follow below steps to create environments where your stage targets on.

Navigate to the Pipelines page. Then choose Environments and click on Create Environment. 
For more information check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#creation)

And Then follow the instruction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops) to create checks for each environment. In this way, before your pipeline stage starts to deploy to an environment with the `checks` defined. It will wait for the approval.

It is suggested to deploy your app with release pipeline. You can create Release pipeline in **Releases** Page in your project. Create **approvals** and **gates** to manually intervene your deployment task is quite straightforward in release pipeline.
Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps

Answer (score 0):

FYI Manual Validation task at the end of each stage is also no available which would accomplish this:

This is now available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

```
- task: ManualValidation@0
  timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
  inputs:
    notifyUsers: |
      test@test.com
      example@example.com
    instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
    onTimeout: 'resume'
```

Comment: To clarify potential questions based on our experience: The Manual _Validation_ task is for YAML pipelines. The Manual _Intervention_ task is for Classic pipelines.